# Tesseract two similar picture, one works, the other doesn't, why?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I use tesseract command line to get OCR result,like this "tesseract "d:\1.jpg" "d:\out" -l chi_sim+eng --psm 7".

1.jpg gets correct result "第 26-61 147151706 期".

2.jpg gets only one char "|".

These two picture looks similar to me,why the result is so different?

what steps can i do to get correct result?

[1.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehGB6.png)

[2.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQVte.png)

Comment: I think you must upgrade to last version: https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki. i try with 2 your images, they output text ok.

Comment: I use tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v5.0.0-alpha.20190708.exe, is it the newest version?

Comment: Which version do you use? Can you tell me?

Comment: i using version Tesseract 4.0.0.

Comment: Thanks, but i still can't get correct result.